# How to import config module following ES6 standard not commonJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I'm mixing some imports and I would like to have all of them using ES6.

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { PasswordItemDTO } from './api/clients/PasswordCheck/model/passwordItemDTO';
import { PasswordErrorsDTO } from './api/clients/PasswordCheck/model/passwordErrorsDTO';
const config = require('config');
```

I would like to use the same way, ES6, for the config module which I used commonJS.

I'm using it to retrieve some information: config.get('item'),

There is a possibility to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can of course `import config from 'config';`. But I'm having a hard time trying to imagine that `config` is the name of a package that can be required in the first place.

Comment: What's your actual question? Did you try `import config from "config"`? Did it fail?

Comment: @GOTO0 https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Comment: @Alberto have you seen https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/521 and https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/pull/622?

Answer (score -1):

There is not other way for now. I checked in lot of websites. Thank you all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Just add this line `dotenv.config();` and you can then use the values in the `.env` file using [destructuring](https://flaviocopes.com/typescript-object-destructuring/) to get your env values.

Comment: [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is not [`config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)